# Application Hangs on SQL Server - restart required every time

Tags: sql-server, windows

We have an application which has a SQL Server 2000 Database attached to it. After every couple of days the application hangs, and we have to restart SQL Server service and then it works fine. SQL Server logs show nothing about the problem. Can anyone tell me how to identify this issue? Is it an application problem or a SQL Server problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it an application problem or a SQL Server problem?

Is it possible to connect to MS SQL Server using Query Analyzer or another instance of your application?

General tips:

- Use Activity Monitor to find information about concurrent processes, locks and resource utilization.
- Use Sql Server Profiler to trace server and database activity, to capture and save data to a table or file to analyze it later.
- You can use Dynamic Management Views (\Database name\Views\System Views folder (in the Management Studio)) to get more detailed information about MS SQL Server internals.
- If you have the problems with perfomance (not your case) - you can use Perfomance Monitor and Data Collector Sets to gather perfomance information

Answer (score 0):

Hard to predict the issue, I will suggest you to check your application first.Check what all operations you are performing against data base, are you taking care of connection pooling, unused open connections can create issues.
Check if you can get any log from your application. Without any log information hardly we can suggest anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Read this**

> ```
> Application may be hanging due to Deadlock
>
> check the SP runs at that time using Profiler 
>
> and check the table manipulation(use nolock), 
>
> check the buffer size and segregate the DB into two or three module.
> ```